# Python multithreading in AWS on lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

How can the following code be modified to allow multithreading in AWS on lambda? The following simplified sample code shows the format of the code that I am trying to use with AWS lambda.

```
bList = [["ab","cd"],
["ef","gh"],
["ij","kl"],
["mn","op"],
["qr","st"]]


def alphabet(feedurl,publishedString):
    feedprocess(feedurl,publishedString)

def feedprocess(url,publishedString):
    print(url)
    print(publishedString)

for i,v in enumerate(bList):
    alphabet(*bList[i])
```

Returns:

```
ab
cd
ef
gh
ij
kl
mn
op
qr
st
```

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: The linked documentation mentions it, but I think it's worth calling out the fact that Lambda has hard execution time and memory limits. If you're _certain_ that's not going to be a problem for your use case, that's fine, but it's something I've run into more than once. Particularly if you're going to be calling out to third party APIs or running other operations with undefined execution times, Lambda might not end up being a good fit.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your code doesn't seem to be doing anything with threads? Have you tried just using threads and what problem are you having?